# Raise NotSupported("Response content isn't text") scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Response content isn't text

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
def parse(self, response):
    `pdf_url = response.xpath(
        '//div[p[contains(text(), "The list becomes official upon '
        'publication in the Official Journal.")]]//a[@class="link-pdf"]/'
        "@href"
    ).get()
    press_release_url_2 = response.meta.get("press_release_url_2")
    print(press_release_url_2)
    #more code`

def get_pdf_url_2(self, response):
    `press_release_url_2 = response.xpath(
        "//a[contains(@href, 'data.consilium.europa.eu/doc/document/')]//@href"
    ).get()
    press_release_response = scrapy.Request(press_release_url_2)
    press_release_response = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(
        url=press_release_url_2,
        body=press_release_response.body.decode("utf-8"),
        encoding="utf-8",
    )
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=press_release_url_2,
        callback=self.parse,
        meta={"press_release_url_2": press_release_url_2},
    )`
```

The error is:

```
  File "/home/lilia/Documents/python/.venv/dj_sanction_lists_spiders/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py", line 132, in xpath
    raise NotSupported("Response content isn't text")
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Response content isn't text
```

Can you explain to me the error and rewrite my code to remove the error?

Also, in the `press_release_url_2` method, the variable outputs the result, but in the parse method, it returns `Nonetype`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the answer doesn't solve your issue, then I suggest creating a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy requests do not work like the `requests` library.  A scrapy request is simply a wrapper that holds the information needed to make the request, the scrapy engine is the one that actually does the fetching and downloading.

In your `get_pdf_url_2` method you are treating the scrapy request as if you would expect to receive the contents immediately, but a request needs to be yielded back to the crawler before you can receive the response in a callback method.

```
press_release_response = scrapy.Request(press_release_url_2)  # < this needs to be yielded
press_release_response = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(   # this will not work
    url=press_release_url_2,
    body=press_release_response.body.decode("utf-8"),
    encoding="utf-8",
)
```

What you can do is simply yield the request and specify an alternative callback, and get the contents that way.

```
def parse(self, response):
    `pdf_url = response.xpath(
        '//div[p[contains(text(), "The list becomes official upon '
        'publication in the Official Journal.")]]//a[@class="link-pdf"]/'
        "@href"
    ).get()
    press_release_url_2 = response.meta.get("press_release_url_2")
    print(press_release_url_2)
    #more code`

def get_pdf_url_2(self, response):
    `press_release_url_2 = response.xpath(
        "//a[contains(@href, 'data.consilium.europa.eu/doc/document/')]//@href"
    ).get()
    yield scrapy.Request(press_release_url_2, callback=self.press_release_parse)
    

def press_release_parse(self, press_release_response):
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=press_release_url_2,
        callback=self.parse,
        meta={"press_release_url_2": press_release_url_2},
    )
```

Your code is a little confusing so I am not certain the above is what you are trying to do.